# How to find creator of JmSession closed by CachedConnectionManager in JBoss

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jbpm

I am getting the following error in my logs on JBoss 5.0.1 with JBPM. I can't for the life of me work out where this session is getting opened and not closed (wherever we use JMS we cleanup the collection inside a finally block).

```
2009-03-05 13:11:12,595 INFO  [org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.CachedConnectionManager] (WorkerThread#1[127.0.0.1:51191]) Closing a connection for you.  Please close them yourself: org.jboss.resource.adapter.jms.JmsSession@11ed463
```

Can anyone offer any pointers as to how I should go about finding where the JmsSession was created so that I can see what went wrong?

Thanks in advance

Rich

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found it - the stack trace below the error message shows the stack for the creation -  and it seems like it's JBPM itself. At first I assumed that it was the stack of where the error occurred (I couldn't imagine JBPM needing to create a message, so discounted the stack trace as not being of much use...) - now I need to work out why!

Comment: Further to that - there was a place where I was getting a JBPMContext, but not closing it at the end.